# Obtaining the total of coincidences with multiple pattern using grep command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file in Linux contains strings:

```
CALLTMA
Starting
Starting
Ending
Starting
Ending
Ending
CALLTMA
Ending
```

I need the quantity of any string (FE. #Ending, # Starting, #CALLTMA). In my example I need obtaining:

```
CALLTMA : 2
Starting: 3
Ending : 4
```

I can obtaining this output when I execute 3 commands:

```
grep -i "Starting" "/myfile.txt" | wc -l
grep -i "Ending" "/myfile.txt" | wc -l
grep -i "CALLTMA" "/myfile.txt" | wc -l
```

I want to know if it is possible to obtain the same output using only one command.

I try running this command

```
grep -iE "CALLTMA|Starting|Ending" "/myfile.txt" | wc -l
```

But this returned the total of coincidences. I appreciate your help .

Comment: Look at the uniq tool. It has a flag for counting unique items in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort` and `uniq`:

```
sort myfile.txt | uniq -c
```

The `-c` adds the counts to the unique lines. If you want to sort the output by frequency, add

```
| sort -n
```

to the end (and change to `-nr` if you want the descending order).

Answer (score 2):

A simple awk way to handle this:

```
awk '{counts[$1]++} END{for (c in counts) print c, counts[c]}' file

Starting 3
Ending 4
CALLTMA 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -c` will work. You can put it all together in a short script:

```
for i in Starting CALLTMA Ending; do 
    printf "%-8s  : %d\n" "$i" $(grep -c "$i" file.txt)
done
```

(to enter the search terms as arguments, just use the arguments array for the loop list, e.g. `for i in "$@"; do`)

**Output**

```
Starting  : 3
CALLTMA   : 2
Ending    : 4
```